# Debugging the C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to build Amaya.  When the build failed with

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token

I ran g++ with only the preprocessor (replacing the -c option with -E) on the file that failed to compile to see what was going on.  This produced an 80,000 line file, showing me that 'Blue' had been replaced by (2 << 8), which clearly explained the error.  If I correct this, the file compiles fine.  I guess I could live with that, but I would like to find out why this is happening.

Is there any way I can track how the preprocessor is replacing a specific string, in this case 'Blue'?

================= Update ===================

Well, I found the culprit:

```
> headers=`g++ [omited for brevity] -M  \
    ../../thotlib/dialogue/AmayaClassicNotebook.cpp`

> for file in $headers ; do grep -s -H Blue $file | grep "(2 << 8)";done 

/usr/local/include/gc.h:#define Blue (2 << 8)
```

So adding #undef Blue fixed the problem. So using this combination of -M and grep seems OK but sometimes C++ preprocessor definitions can be a real forest; I was curious whether there were some better way, some clever GNU tool maybe.

Answer (score 12):

I find running

```
g++ ... -dD -E $file > $file.ii
```

to be very useful in untangling preprocessing problems. From `man g++`:

```
-dD Dump all macro definitions, at the end of preprocessing,
    in addition to normal output.
```

Comment: Seems that neither -dD nor -E output anything if there's a syntax error detected during preprocessing, which is a bit inconvenient in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

If nobody comes up with anything better (based on the source line info in the preprocessed file), you could use the -M option to get a list of headers included by the source file, and search those for "Blue". I expect it's possible for some kind of obfuscation to mean that this doesn't find what you're looking for, but normally you'll turn up the definition somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the perennial

```
find /src -exec grep Blue {} /dev/null ';'
```

That usually works for me, at least as a first cut.

Comment: Another place to grep is system headers like /usr/include.

Comment: In this case, the #define was in a system location, not in a file under the source directory